# What's the PostGIS equivalent to Extract Nodes in fTools / QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, vertices, ftools

I'm looking to convert Park polygons from OSM into points.

The QGIS fTools [Extract Nodes](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_ftools.html) tool will convert a polygon to points at the vertices.

What is the equivalent function or work-flow in PostGIS?

[image]

Comment: I will confess that the other question goes a step further to get coordinates, and not just using st_dump to get the points, so my flag of duplicate may have been a bit hasty. I apologize if you consider this to be significantly different to not warrant marking as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo can use [ST_DumpPoints(geom)](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_DumpPoints.html) to get the points listed.

Look at the example how to use it.

The result contains both the geometry and a path telling where in the polygon the point belongs. So to just get the geometry (points) do like this:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom
```

Comment: I'm struggling with visualizing this result - any thoughts? Is that what 'i' is?

Comment: mapBaker -- what are you using for visualizing.  Not sure what Nicklas meant by i.  There is a path property which is an array of integers defining depth in geometry.  You should be able to visualize this in QGIS DbManager with -  ``SELECT (g).path[1], (g).geom FROM (SELECT ST_DumpPoints(geom) As g FROM sometable) As f;``

Comment: Just a typo. It should have been "it" :-)

Comment: @LR1234567 I can only get PATH values of '1' for that query. I am getting back the correct number of nodes, so for now, I'll say I need to work on my workflow for how to use these points... Thank you both!

Comment: If you have polygons/multipolygs path[1] is the index of the polygon the point belongs to.  Not interesting unless you have a multipolygon.  path[2] would be the ring . path[3] would be the index position of the point in the ring.  So I'm guessing maybe what you want is path[3]

Comment: @LR1234567 revisiting this now and it makes perfect sense... If I knew then what I know now...

Comment: @NicklasAvén thanks again for this - works like a charm!