# extract separate nodes in Postgis equivalent QGIS

Tags: postgis, extract

I want to extract nodes from polygon in Postgis like it QGIS "extract nodes" tool does. I've red the answered question about this in [What's the PostGIS equivalent to Extract Nodes in fTools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136326/whats-the-postgis-equivalent-to-extract-nodes-in-ftools-qgis) and used ST_DumpPoints(geom) function. But the result contains both the geometry and a path telling where in the polygon the point belongs. (ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom gives the geometry (points), OK.
The problem is that I can't address to single node from geometries, because tool ST_DumpPoints return integer indexes (path) of the polygon the point belongs to. In short, when I visualize my dump points in QGIS, I have no possibility to select one single node - all nodes of polygon have been **filtered** (picture 2), but **selected** is only one. As a consequence, I can't implement any spatial analysis with every separate node (e.g. verification about other layer contains any of this nodes).
[image: nodes]
[image: picture 2]

How I can simply get the points without connection to the polygons?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the geometry of the point dump. The example in the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) returns two columns, one for the path and one for the geometry, but you can do it in a single query. You will get all points (one by row) sorted by feature.

```
select mylayer.id, (st_dumpPoints(the_geom)).geom  from mylayer order by mylayer.id;
```

** **EDIT** **

An option to display the nodes in QGIS is to create a spatial view. You would query the polygons, get the points and wrap that in another query to be able to construct a unique ID. It has the advantage of being linked to your polygons, reflecting any edits. However it is slow.... if too slow, it might be easier to create a new layer with the vertices.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.sv_myLayerNodes AS 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  myLayerID, ptnode) AS V_UID, 
    myLayerID, 
    ptnode
  FROM (SELECT 
        myLayerID,
        (st_dumpPoints(the_geom)).geom as ptnode
    FROM public.myLayer
)b;
```

Comment: I got the points, (st_dumpPoints(the_geom)).geom returned me geometries, but the problem is that I can't select one single node, all nodes of polygon have been filtered (picture 2), although selected is only one.

Comment: Please see edit for a way of displaying the nodes